# How to detect if checkbox is checked after form submited

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a simple form which lists a bunch of rows from my database.  I have added a checkbox.  If the user checks the checkbox I would like to delete that row when the form has been submited.

```
 <EditForm Model="@samples" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach (var forecast in samples)
        {
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="delete" name="delete" value="@forecast.Id" bind="@forecast.Id" /></td>
                <td>@forecast.Id</td>
                <td>@forecast.Title</td>
                <td>@forecast.Description</td>
            </tr>
        }
        <button type="submit">Delete selected</button>
        <button @onclick=@Navigate>Add</button>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </EditForm>
```

My issue is that I cant figure out how to detect if the user has selected the checkbox.

```
private async void HandleValidSubmit()
{
    
    using var context = DbFactory.CreateDbContext();
    
    foreach (var sample in samples)
    {
        // check here if checkbox was checked.
        
        //context.Samples.Remove(sample);

    }

    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating something to hold the samples that were deleted

```
<input type="checkbox" @onchange="@(async (e) => ToggleDelete(@sample))"/>
```

Then in code I add them to a list.

```
private List<Sample> deleteSamples = new List<Sample>();

private void ToggleDelete(Sample sample)
    {
        if (deleteSamples.Contains(sample))
        {
            deleteSamples.Remove(sample);
        }
        else
        {
            deleteSamples.Add(sample);
        }
    }
```

Which then lets me delete everything

```
private async void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        using var context = DbFactory.CreateDbContext();

        foreach (var sample in deleteSamples)
        {
            context.Samples.Remove(sample);
        }

        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```